# Consider of drawing one card from a deck of $52$. Prove that the events of a spade being drawn and an ace being drawn are independent events.

Tags: probability, independence

> Consider of drawing one card from a deck of $52$. Prove that the events of a spade being drawn and an ace being drawn are independent events.

Let $A$ be the event that a spade is drawn and let $B$ be the event that an ace is drawn.

Then, $\text P(A) = 4/52 = 1/13$ and $\text P(B) = 4/52 = 1/13$.

How can I calculate $\text P(A\cap B)$? And how can I prove that these events are independent since the question specifically asked to prove that they are independent?

Comment: What card did you get in $A \cap B$? What is the probability that you drew that card? What is the definition of independence?

Comment: $P(A\cap B)$ is the probability that the card drawn is both an ace and a spade.

Comment: Independence is determined by $\text P(A\cap B)=\text P(A)\times\text P(B)$

Comment: In a deck of 52 cards there should be more than four spades be present ...

Comment: Is there really a $1/13$ probability of drawing a spade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't compute the probability of event $A$ correctly. There are $13$ spades in a standard deck. So $P(A)=13/52=1/4$. Note that $A\cap B$ corresponds to drawing the ace of spades and hence 
$$
\frac{1}{52}=P(A\cap B)=\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{13}=P(A)P(B)
$$

Comment: Thank you so very much!!!